# PHP Timezone bug: adding extra hour

Tags: php, timezone

I have problem...

I'm currently working with "America/Santiago" timezone, and whenever I create a datetime object with a hour < 01:00AM, it adds 1 hour.

Example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Santiago');
$dateTest = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i:s', '04/09/2022 00:32:27');
print_r($dateTest);
```

This prints:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2022-09-04 01:32:27.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Santiago
)
```

But if I create the following object:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Santiago');
$dateTest = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i:s', '04/09/2022 01:22:11');
print_r($dateTest);
```

prints:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2022-09-04 01:22:11.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Santiago
)
```

I'm really lost here, can someone guide ?

Thanks

Comment: Kind of interesting that PHP 8.0.23 and greater work as expected: https://3v4l.org/T4KO1. Doesn't help you, unfortunately.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to Chile's DST changes? https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/chile-dst-delay-2022.html

Comment: Most likely. I tried updating the timezonedb , but the lastest update (https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb) is not available for Windows yet